# How to create a class/scope method that orders objects based on values from an instance method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, arel, class-method

I’ve been struggling for hours trying to develop a class or scope method, but have a beginner knowledge of SQLite and everything I’ve tried and read has thus far failed.

I’m trying to find a way to order lists by their average rating.

I have a has_many/belongs_to association between List and Rating. Lists have_many Ratings, each List can have_many ratings. I then have an instance method that calculates a list’s average rating:

```
def average_rating
   self.ratings.average(:rating).to_i
end
```

I’m now trying to find a way to order lists by their average rating, but am not having any success. Following another post, I tried this method:

```
 def self.highest_rating
    List.all.sort_by(&:average_rating)
 end
```

But it simply returns the all the lists in no particular order. With this query:

```
 SELECT AVG("ratings"."rating") FROM "ratings" WHERE   "ratings"."rated_id" = ?
```

I've thought of making average_rating an attribute on the List model, but have had difficulty even developing a scope method for that. If you could offer any advice or assistance I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can sort your query results by any column not the value. When you trying to sort by average rating as you do it now you like

```
List.all.sort_by(5) # you sort by result of the method which is simple number
```

It's not make big sense though.

I believe you need to add `average_rating` column to your `List` model. You will be able to calculate average rating for every list and store that value in the column and then sort lists by that column like this

```
def self.highest_rating
  List.all.order(average_rating)
end
```

To calculate your average rating you may use callback every time you're creating new rating. It may look like:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :calculate_average

  private
    def calculate_average
      #your code
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks for your help! i'm going to add the attribute like you suggested.